Fabric connection to Oracle on-premise using data pipelines
I'm trying to get a connection working in Fabric using data pipelines to extract data from an on-premise Oracle database to an Azure SQL Database. The gateway is installed on the server & the necessary requirements are met.
I am getting the following error when retrieving the tables, or trying the connection:
Please check your network connectivity to ensure your on-premises data gateway can access we.frontend.clouddatahub.net and restart the service to retry the connection again once the connectivity issue has been resolved.

Connecting and loading tables using Power BI on the server where the on-premise data gateway is installed is working.
Using data flows, with the same connection, to connect to the Oracle database is also working.
It's only when I'm using data pipelines that the connection is no longer working.


Can you provide connection configurations and expected output?
